# Is there an application where you can easily pinpoint parts of a HTML markup?

Tags: html

As my markup is becoming larger and larger I am having difficulty going back and forth with the css. I know google chrome has something like that but I forgot how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can access the Chrome dev tool with F12.. or you can just right click and then click `Inspect Element`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probably referring to the Chrome Developer Tools. Right click on the page => `Inspect Element`. That will then open the developer tools.

From there you can hover over the HTML code and it will highlight the relevant section of the page. You will then be able to edit the CSS code directly using the pane on the right to see its immediate effects. Usually I play around with CSS that way before actually coding it into the CSS file. Remember to also disable the cache when developing.

You can find a good tutorial here (which also covers all the other features):
https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/